# Converting CastleWindsor-code to Unity-code

Tags: c#, unity-container, castle-windsor

I used the write the following in Windsor Castle :

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        //Makes sure we only get one DbConnection
        container.Register(Component.For<IMyMusicSession>().UsingFactoryMethod(_ => new MyMusicSession("MyMusicDb")).LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
```

How can I do the same in MS Unity?
I'm new to Unity, so that's why I ask the question.
The "MyMusicDb" is actually the name of the connectionstring as written in the web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IMyMusicSession>(
    new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(c => new MyMusicSession("MyMusicDb")));
```

Be sure to install the [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) NuGet package.